# How do I load a Segp1 file into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal, kmz

Previously I loaded segp1 files into google earth using a earthpoints program, and then I loaded the google earth kmz file into QGIS project, I want to find a better way? I think there is a GDAL plugin but I am very new to GIS and don't know where to add plugin?

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to download any plugin to read SEG-P1 format as it is natively supported by [GDAL](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/segukooa.html) hence QGIS can open it easily.

Simply read the file as a vector layer, (`Layer > Add Layer >  Add Vector Layer` and choose the file); QGIS will find your SEG-P1 files if their file extension is `*.seg` (or others as you see in the below image).

[image]

SEG-P1 seems an [old format](https://www.iogp.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/P1andP2flyer-EMAIL.pdf) and I could not find downloadable samples, except for one available at a commercial site [pulse seismic](http://www.pulseseismic.com/downloads) - which I could successfully open with QGIS.

Comment: I tried the same pulse seismic data and it loaded fine, The data I'm trying to load isn't formatted correctly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Rob2021 The [GDAL](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/segukooa.html) page has a link to the description of SEG-P1 format. It is a kind of ASCII format, so you may be able to reformat or edit your data to comply with the specification. Good luck!

Comment: I modified my file with an H on the header lines and it read fine, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So as a follow-up to this question, according to this website (https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html?highlight=segy) "The following drivers have been retired and moved to the https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal-extra-drivers repository: AeronavFAA, BNA, HTF, OpenAir, SEGUKOOA, SEGY, SUA, XPlane"

My follow-on question is whether anyone can explain how to add the 'retired' SEGY driver so that I'm able to read SEGY files in QGIS. I'm not experienced with GitHub so I'm hoping you might make any explanation very explicit.

Thanks.